# Pytorch Gridsample - Can't get Toy example to work

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to understand how to use Pytorch's grid sample function. I understand that we pass in a [B * Channel * H * W] and a flowfield [B * H * W * 2] of UV pixels

But it doesn't seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import time

import cv2

rgbimg = np.ones((100,100,3)).astype(np.float32)*0.5
rgbimg[0:50,0:50,:] = 0

rgbimg_tensor = torch.tensor(rgbimg.transpose(2,0,1)).unsqueeze(0)


flowfield = torch.ones((1,rgbimg.shape[0], rgbimg.shape[1], 2))*0

rgbimg_tensor_trans = F.grid_sample(rgbimg_tensor, flowfield)


rgbimg_trans = rgbimg_tensor_trans[0,:,:,:].numpy().transpose(1,2,0)

print(rgbimg_trans.shape)

cv2.namedWindow("fimage")
cv2.moveWindow("fimage", 2500, 50)
cv2.imshow("fimage", rgbimg_trans)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here I have set the flowfield to zero, but it just seems to set the final image to the same value everywhere. What am I doing wrong

[image]

becomes

[image]

Comment: Okay it looks like in grid sample, if i set 0, its going to sample from all locations in the middle of the image. So the question is how can I rewrite the flowfield I have [physically represents the uv changes] to what pytorch expects?

Answer (score 0):

How about add interpolation parameter ?

e.g.,         x = F.grid_sample(img,
grid,
mode='bilinear',
padding_mode='border')

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the original grid coordinates and normalize to [-1,1]. Below is the revised version:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rows, cols = 100, 100
rgbimg = np.ones((rows, cols,3)).astype(np.float32)*0.5
rgbimg[0:rows//2,0:cols//2,:] = 0

rgbimg_tensor = torch.tensor(rgbimg.transpose(2,0,1)).unsqueeze(0)

row_coords, col_coords = np.meshgrid(np.arange(rows), np.arange(cols), indexing='ij')
flow = np.zeros((rows, cols, 2), dtype=float) - 5
grid = np.array([row_coords + flow[:, :, 0], col_coords + flow[:, :, 1]])
grid[0, :, :] = 2.0 * grid[0, :, :] / (rows-1) - 1.0
grid[1, :, :] = 2.0 * grid[1, :, :] / (cols-1) - 1.0

flowfield = torch.tensor(grid.transpose(2,1,0)).unsqueeze(0).float()

rgbimg_tensor_trans = F.grid_sample(rgbimg_tensor, flowfield, align_corners = True)

rgbimg_trans = rgbimg_tensor_trans[0,:,:,:].numpy().transpose(1,2,0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6, 3))
axes[0].imshow(rgbimg)
axes[0].set_title('Original')
axes[1].imshow(rgbimg_trans)
axes[1].set_title('Transformed')
plt.show()
```

You should get result:

[image]